# Download custom modernizr.js from Modernizr Download Builder

Tags: modernizr

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) provides a [Download Builder](http://modernizr.com/download/#-boxshadow-hsla-opacity-canvas-canvastext-audio-svg-shiv-cssclasses-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-load) tool where certain tests can be chosen and the source code for that set of tests is provided. At the top of the generated output is a URL to return to that particular build.

It seems not be a far step from there to provide a URL where I could use Curl to download the source of that particular build. Alas, I have not found a way to do this so far. Just wondering if anyone out there knows of a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

you need check the features that you want, after that click on build on the top right of the screen. Another way is click on development build on the home page, you will be send to the build page with all options already checked, after that click on build and a pop up will show with the option to download the file.